# MSP430F5529 with GY-9250 X Y and Z values are all 0

Tags: msp430, mpu

Hi I have my Gyroscope linked up to my MSP430F5529 like so:
VCC -> 5V
GND -> GND
SCL -> P3.1
SDA -> P3.0

And here is my Code for the MSP430:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define GYRO_ADDRESS 0x68

void I2C_Init();
void readGyroscope(int* x, int* y, int* z);

void main() {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
    printf("Starting...\n");
    P3SEL |= 0x03;
    printf("Configuring I2C pins...\n");

    I2C_Init();
    printf("Initializing I2C...\n");

    while (1) {
        int x, y, z;
        readGyroscope(&x, &y, &z);
        printf("X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d\n", x, y, z);
        __delay_cycles(1000000);
    }
}

void I2C_Init() {
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSWRST;
    UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;
    UCB0BR0 = 12;
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0I2CSA = GYRO_ADDRESS;
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2;
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
}

void readGyroscope(int* x, int* y, int* z) {
    UCB0I2CSA = GYRO_ADDRESS;
    printf("Setting gyroscope address...\n");

    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    UCB0TXBUF = 0x43;
    printf("Transmitting data...\n");

    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    *x = (int)(UCB0RXBUF << 8);

    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    *x |= UCB0RXBUF;
    *x = (*x << 8) >> 8;

    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    *y = (int)(UCB0RXBUF << 8);

    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    *y |= UCB0RXBUF;
    *y = (*y << 8) >> 8;

    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
    *z = (int)(UCB0RXBUF << 8);
    *z = (*z << 8) >> 8;
}
```

However, when I run the program, I constantly receive the following output:

```
X: 0, Y: 0, Z: 0
```

I tried waiting for the Buffer to be full but its stuck in this loop forever:

```
while (!(UCB0IFG & UCRXIFG));
```

Comment: Do you really want to generate a I2C start condition every time you read a byte (`UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;`)? At a high level you do not follow the correct sequence to read from the gyro. You need to start, write the slave address, write the register address, repeat start, then read the data bytes. All the while checking for the bytes to be receivied and no NACKs. Have you got a good I2C example for the MSP430 and the MPU-9250 datasheet (https://invensense.tdk.com/download-pdf/mpu-9250-datasheet/)?